# T-SQL table variable data order

Tags: t-sql

I have a UDF which returns table variable like

```
--
--
RETURNS @ElementTable TABLE
(
    ElementID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    ElementValue VARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS
--
--
```

Is the order of data in this table variable guaranteed to be same as the order data is inserted into it. e.g. if I issue

```
INSERT INTO @ElementTable(ElementValue) VALUES ('1')
INSERT INTO @ElementTable(ElementValue) VALUES ('2')
INSERT INTO @ElementTable(ElementValue) VALUES ('3')
```

I expect data will always be returned in that order when I say

```
select ElementValue from @ElementTable  --Here I don't use order by
```

**EDIT:**

If order by is not guaranteed then the following query

```
SELECT T1.ElementValue,T2.ElementValue FROM dbo.MyFunc() T1
Cross Apply dbo.MyFunc T2
order by t1.elementid
```

will not produce 9x9 matrix as

```
1 1
1 2
1 3
2 1
2 2
2 3
3 1
3 2
3 3
```

consistently.

Is there any possibility that it could be like

```
1 2
1 1
1 3
2 3
2 2
2 1
3 1
3 2
3 3
```

How to do it using my above function?

Comment: There are so many questions, that all have the same answer. Unless you specify an `ORDER BY` for the query that's actually returning the results (e.g. isn't a subquery, embedded in a view, etc), there's no ordering guarantees.

Comment: ORDER BY _is_ guaranteed to give you the correct order. I'm not sure what you are asking now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your update, you obtain it in the obvious way - you ask the system to give you the results in the order you want:

```
SELECT T1.ElementValue,T2.ElementValue FROM dbo.MyFunc() T1
Cross join dbo.MyFunc() T2
order by t1.elementid, t2.elementid
```

You *are* guaranteed that if you're using inefficient single row inserts within your UDF, that the IDENTITY values will match the order in which the individual `INSERT` statements were specified.

Answer (score 4):

No, the order is not guaranteed to be the same.

Unless, of course you are using ORDER BY. Then it is guaranteed to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Order is not guaranteed.

But if all you want is just simply to get your records back *in the same order you inserted them*, then just order by your primary key.  Since you already have that field setup as an auto-increment, it should suffice.

Comment: See the edit section of my question. I need explanation on that

Answer (score 0):

...or use a deterministic function

```
SELECT TOP 9 
  M1 = (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id) + 2) / 3,
  M2 = (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id) + 2) % 3 + 1
FROM 
  sysobjects

M1  M2
1   1
1   2
1   3
2   1
2   2
2   3
3   1
3   2
3   3
```